# Getting "ClassNotFoundException: org.classpathopenejb.loader.LoaderServlet" on deployment at Glassfish 4

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror

I've installed `Glassfish` `4` to use with a java web project I developed so far using `Tomcat` `7`.

The problem is I am getting this exception after the initialization of the logger and primefaces. **This is how the message starts:**

```
[2014-08-31T02:08:44.335+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1409440124335] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet loader as unavailable]]

[2014-08-31T02:08:44.336+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1409440124336] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WebModule[]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) org.classpathopenejb.loader.LoaderServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.classpathopenejb.loader.LoaderServlet
```

The exceptions trace printed below with a root cause is [here](http://pastebin.com/Mzu6hEF4).

What is the problem?

I've tried adding this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
     <artifactId>openejb-loader</artifactId>
     <version>4.6.0.2</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml, and no success.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had left the a `servlet` mapping at the deployment descriptor in an attempt to integrate `OpenEJB` with `Tomcat` `7`.

Removed that and now it works fine.